# Do I have to use .setup to switch video file in jwplayer?

Tags: jwplayer

When changing the video file on a page I would have thought `jwplayer().file(embedurl);` (or similar) would have been fine and all the previous properties of the embed would have been preserved. However, I can't seem to find anything like that and documentation suggests that I would have to basically set it all up again:

```
jwplayer().setup({ 
    file: embedurl, 
    height: 360,
    width: 640 
});
```

What is the simplest way of switching out a vid with a new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to use:
`jwplayer.load([{file, image}]);`

`file` can be a single video or audio file or a RSS playlist.

`image` is optional.

Ref. http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413089-javascript-api-reference

There's a load of options on that page so use <kbd>Ctrl + F</kbd> and search for ".load"
JW Player's documentation is not very helpful to beginners so if you need further details, let me know. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks very much. Yes, am finding certain things hard to nut out from jwplayers docs! :) Is strange to find this answer in a section titled 'Playlists'!? Thanks again.

Comment: Believe it or not, the documentation used to be WORSE. At least most of the stuff is now on just a few pages on their site.

Comment: Here is another example - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1439570-example-loading-new-playlists